# Chaining multiple filter() in Django returning nothing

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

**I was trying to filter two conditions but it's not returning anything**
**That's the function that has the condition i'm using**

```
def airport_view(request, code):
    airport = Airport.objects.get(code=code)
    flights = Flight.objects.filter(origin=airport).filter(destination=airport)
    context = {
        'airport':airport,
        'flights':flights
    }
    return render(request, "flights/airport.html", context)
```

**The airport works normally but the multiple filter chain doesn't work, even that i got three flights which has one of both conditions**
**That's the related models if it helps you**

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey('Airport', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="From")
    destination = models.ForeignKey('Airport', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="To")
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField('Person', blank=True)
```

Comment: You here look for flights from and to the same `Airport`?

Comment: yes, i want to show all flights from and to a specific airport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a disjunction of conditions, you can work with `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

flights = Flight.objects.filter(Q(origin=airport) | Q(destination=airport))
```

this will retrieve `Flight`s that have as *origin*, or as *destination* the given `airport`.

If you chain the filters together, you define a *conjunction*, so in this case you were looking for `Flight`s that had as origin *and* as destination the `airport`.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.